# How do I clear a Panel?

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that starts with an Empty Panel and then When I press a button that panel will be filled with some other panel that contains elements.

But if I press the button again it overlaps and stacks over and over becoming something very ugly.

How can I clear the panel every time I press the button so it will not overlap.
Notice that I've used `removeAll()` `UpdateUI()` and none worked. Here,s my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel NumberPanel = new JPanel();
    String[] ButtonString = {"7", "8", "9", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "0", ".", "+/-"};
    JButton ButtonArray[] = new JButton[ButtonString.length];
    JPanel OperationPanel = new JPanel();
    String[] OperationString = {"Erase", "Ac", "*", "/", "+", "-", "Ans", "="};
    JButton[] OperationArray = new JButton[OperationString.length];
    JTextField WritingZone = new JTextField(27);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Exit");
    double first = 0;
    double second = 0;
    double result = 0;
    char operation = ' ';

    Calculator() {
        super("Project Wolverine");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel radio1 = new JPanel();
        final JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("Simple Calculator");
        final JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("Advanced Calculator");
        ButtonGroup g1 = new ButtonGroup();
        g1.add(r1);
        g1.add(r2);
        radio1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
        radio1.add(r1);
        radio1.add(r2);
        radio1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a calculator"));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
        panel2.add(b1);
        panel2.add(b2);
        radio1.add(panel2);
        add(BorderLayout.WEST, radio1);
        final JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
        emptyPanel.setVisible(false);
        emptyPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(BorderLayout.EAST, emptyPanel);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                emptyPanel.removeAll();
                if (e.getSource() == b1) {

                    if (r1.isSelected()) {
                        for (int a = 0; a < ButtonArray.length; a++) {
                            ButtonArray[a] = new JButton(ButtonString[a]);
                        }
                        NumberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 5, 5));
                        for (int a = 0; a < ButtonArray.length; a++) {
                            NumberPanel.add(ButtonArray[a]);
                        }

                        for (int a = 0; a < OperationArray.length; a++) {
                            OperationArray[a] = new JButton(OperationString[a]);
                        }
                        OperationPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 5, 5));
                        for (int a = 0; a < OperationArray.length; a++) {
                            OperationPanel.add(OperationArray[a]);
                        }

                        JPanel Finalpanel = new JPanel();
                        Finalpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                        Finalpanel.add(NumberPanel);
                        Finalpanel.add(OperationPanel);

                        WritingZone.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                        WritingZone.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
                        WritingZone.setEditable(false);
                        WritingZone.setBackground(Color.white);
                        JPanel TextPanel = new JPanel();
                        TextPanel.add(WritingZone);

                        for (int a = 0; a < ButtonArray.length; a++) {
                            ButtonArray[a].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    for (int a = 0; a < ButtonArray.length - 1; a++) {
                                        if (e.getSource() == ButtonArray[a]) {
                                            String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                            WritingZone.setText(temp + ButtonArray[a].getText());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        ButtonArray[11].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if (e.getSource() == ButtonArray[11]) {
                                    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                                    temp.append(WritingZone.getText());
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    for (int a = 0; a < temp.length(); a++) {
                                        if (temp.charAt(a) == '-') {
                                            temp.deleteCharAt(a);
                                            WritingZone.setText(temp.toString());
                                        } else {
                                            WritingZone.setText("-" + temp.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if (e.getSource() == OperationArray[0]) {
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    String temp2 = "";
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    for (int x = 0; x < temp.length() - 1; x++) {
                                        temp2 += (Character.toString(temp.charAt(x)));
                                    }
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if (e.getSource() == OperationArray[1]) {
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    first = 0;
                                    second = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation = OperationArray[2].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation = OperationArray[3].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation = OperationArray[4].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[5].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation = OperationArray[5].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[6].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                String temp = String.valueOf(result);
                                String temp2 = WritingZone.getText();
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                WritingZone.setText(temp2 + "" + temp);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[7].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if (operation == '*') {
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result = (first * second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                } else if (operation == '/') {
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    if (second < 0) {
                                        result = (first / second);
                                        String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp2);

                                    } else if (second > 0) {
                                        result = (first / second);
                                        String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp2);

                                    } else if (second == 0) {
                                        WritingZone.setText("Error! Can't divide by 0");
                                    }
                                } else if (operation == '+') {
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result = (first + second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                } else if (operation == '-') {
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result = (first - second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        final JPanel AllPanel = new JPanel();
                        AllPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
                        AllPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, TextPanel);
                        AllPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, Finalpanel);
                        AllPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Simple Calculator"));
                        emptyPanel.add(AllPanel);
                        emptyPanel.setVisible(true);
                        pack();

                    }
                }
            }

        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        JFrame frame = new Calculator();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at some of the panels that are involved...

`NumberPanel`, `OperationPanel`, `WritingZone` which are instance variables and `emptyPane` which is a `final` local variable.

Each of these will either need to be "cleared" or recreated.

A simple solution would be to have `emptyPane` as the only instance variable and simple call `emptyPane.removeAll()` each to the `ActionListener` is triggered, but as it stands, you're going to have to call `removeAll` on each of the fore-mentioned panels, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    emptyPanel.removeAll();
    NumberPanel.removeAll();
    OperationPanel.removeAll();
    WritingZone.setText(null);
```

Now, personally, I would start by creating a `BasicCalculatorPane` and an `AdvancedCalculatorPane`.  Each containing the required UI elements and logic to make them work.  Then when the user selects between them, remove what ever calculator pane is on the screen and create a new instance of the required calculator and add it.  Equally, you could maintain a single instance of reach, but provide a "reset" option, which would allow you to reset the interface, but would save you from having to create more instances of these panels

Comment: It worked. Did as you said and got the result i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
yourPanel.getContentPane().removeAll();//clean main screen Frame
yourPanel.add(newContent);//add the desire Panel
yourPanel.revalidate();
```

Comment: Given the fact the OP is calling `pack`, `validate` is irrlevent, besides which, generally `revalidate` is more useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public class Calculator  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel NumberPanel = new JPanel();
    String [] ButtonString = {"7","8","9","4","5","6","1","2","3","0",".","+/-"};
    JButton ButtonArray [] = new JButton[ButtonString.length];
    JPanel OperationPanel = new JPanel();
    String [] OperationString = {"Erase","Ac","*","/","+","-","Ans","="};
    JButton [] OperationArray = new JButton [OperationString.length];
    JTextField WritingZone = new JTextField(27);
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Exit");
    double first = 0;
    double second = 0;
    double result = 0;
    char operation = ' ';
    Calculator (){
        super("Project Wolverine");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        JPanel radio1 = new JPanel();
        final JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("Simple Calculator");
        final JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("Advanced Calculator");
        ButtonGroup g1 = new ButtonGroup();
        g1.add(r1);
        g1.add(r2);
        radio1.setLayout(new GridLayout (3,1,5,5));
        radio1.add(r1);
        radio1.add(r2);
        radio1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a calculator"));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        panel2.add(b1);
        panel2.add(b2);
        radio1.add(panel2);
        add(BorderLayout.WEST, radio1);
        final JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
        emptyPanel.setVisible(false);
        emptyPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(BorderLayout.EAST, emptyPanel);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                if (e.getSource()==b1){

                if (r1.isSelected()){
                    for (int a = 0 ; a < ButtonArray.length ; a++){
                        ButtonArray[a]= new JButton (ButtonString[a]);
                    }
                    NumberPanel.removeAll();
                    NumberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,5,5));
                    for (int a = 0 ; a < ButtonArray.length ; a++){
                        NumberPanel.add(ButtonArray[a]);
                    }

                    for (int a = 0 ; a < OperationArray.length ; a++){
                        OperationArray[a]= new JButton(OperationString[a]);
                    }
                    OperationPanel.removeAll();
                    OperationPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,5,5));
                    for (int a = 0 ; a < OperationArray.length ; a++){
                        OperationPanel.add(OperationArray[a]);
                    }

                    JPanel Finalpanel = new JPanel();
                    Finalpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    Finalpanel.add(NumberPanel);Finalpanel.add(OperationPanel);


                    WritingZone.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                    WritingZone.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
                    WritingZone.setEditable(false);
                    WritingZone.setBackground(Color.white);
                    JPanel TextPanel = new JPanel();
                    TextPanel.add(WritingZone);


                    for(int a = 0 ; a < ButtonArray.length; a++){
                        ButtonArray[a].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                for (int a = 0; a < ButtonArray.length-1; a++){
                                    if(e.getSource()==ButtonArray[a]){
                                        String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp+ButtonArray[a].getText());
                                    }
                                }
                           }
                        });
                    }
                    ButtonArray[11].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            if(e.getSource()==ButtonArray[11]){
                                StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                                temp.append(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                for (int a = 0; a < temp.length(); a++){
                                    if (temp.charAt(a)=='-'){
                                        temp.deleteCharAt(a);
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp.toString());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        WritingZone.setText("-"+temp.toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });


                        OperationArray[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                if(e.getSource()==OperationArray[0]){
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    String temp2 = "";
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    for (int x = 0 ; x < temp.length()-1 ; x++){
                                        temp2+=(Character.toString(temp.charAt(x)));
                                    }
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                if (e.getSource()==OperationArray[1]){
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    first = 0;
                                    second = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation=OperationArray[2].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation=OperationArray[3].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation=OperationArray[4].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[5].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                first = Double.valueOf(WritingZone.getText());
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                operation=OperationArray[5].getText().charAt(0);
                            }
                        });

                        OperationArray[6].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                String temp = String.valueOf(result);
                                String temp2 = WritingZone.getText();
                                WritingZone.setText("");
                                WritingZone.setText(temp2+""+temp);
                            }
                        });


                        OperationArray[7].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                if (operation=='*'){
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result=(first*second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                                else if(operation=='/'){
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    if(second<0){
                                        result=(first/second);
                                        String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp2);

                                    }
                                    else if (second>0){
                                        result=(first/second);
                                        String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                        WritingZone.setText(temp2);

                                    }
                                    else if (second==0)
                                        WritingZone.setText("Error! Can't divide by 0");
                                }
                                else if (operation=='+'){
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result=(first+second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                                else if (operation=='-'){
                                    String temp = WritingZone.getText();
                                    WritingZone.setText("");
                                    second = Double.valueOf(temp);
                                    result=(first-second);
                                    String temp2 = String.valueOf(result);
                                    WritingZone.setText(temp2);
                                }
                            }
                        });




                    final JPanel AllPanel = new JPanel();
                    AllPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                    AllPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, TextPanel);
                    AllPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, Finalpanel);
                    AllPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Simple      Calculator"));
                    emptyPanel.removeAll();
                    emptyPanel.add(AllPanel);
                    emptyPanel.setVisible(true);
                    pack();


            }}
        }



        });

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(e.getSource()==b2)
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        });}
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void main (String [] arg){






    JFrame frame = new Calculator ();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);}}
```

Just remove all components from emptyPanel, NumberPanel,OperationPanel

```
emptyPanel.removeAll();
NumberPanel.removeAll();
OperationPanel.removeAll();
```